# Implementing limited Type Erasure in C++, which prevents assigment of unlike underlying types

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Type Erasure takes various different forms depending on the author. Here we are discussing Type Erasure using the Concept-Model ideom.

Here's a rough sketch of what this looks like.

```
class TypeErased
{

    template<typename T>
    TypeErased(T value)
        : p_impl(new Model(value))
    {
    }

    TypeErased(const TypeErased& other)
        : p_impl(other.p_impl->clone())
    {
    }

    TypeErased(TypeErased&& other);

    TypeErased& operator=(const TypeErased& other);

    TypeErased& operator=(TypeErased&& other);

    virtual ~TypeErased() = default;

private:

    Concept *p_impl;

    struct Concept
    {
        virtual ~Concept() = default;
        virtual Concept* clone() = 0;
        virtual void virtualfunction() = 0; // others follow
    };

    typename<T>
    struct Model : Concept
    {
        void virtualfunction() override;
        Concept* clone() override;
        T data;
    };

};
```

This has one undesirable property. The following compiles.

```
TypeErased anInteger(1);
TypeErased aString("Hello");

anInteger = aString;
```

Is there a way to prevent `anInteger = aString` from compiling. In other words, can the type be injected back into the `operator=` somehow and prevent assignment of objects with different underlying types?

There might be a way to implement this using templates (which is what I am aiming to do).

- There may also be a way to implement this using RTI and something like an `assert` - but I didn't figure out an elegant way of doing this. It can be probably be done using an enum tag which "remembers" what the underlying type is, but this isn't exactly what I would call an elegant solution. This has the further disadvantage of moving something to a runtime decision rather than being a compile time decision.

If you want a reference for Type Erasure using the above described technique you can find an example from this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bIhUE5uUFOA).

Comment: What's even the purpose is? Why forbid the assignment? Wasn't `TypeErasure`'s purpose so one could store in it whatever? If you don't want `anInteger = aString` to compile just use native types.

Comment: You can check out an implementation of `std::function` one can assign it any type that certain concept - that it can be invoked in certain way.

Comment: The operands of operator `=` both are lvalues of type `TypeErased`. Note that this is not different, if bot `TypeErased` objects contain `int`s. For the compiler to produce an error here, it would produce errors for both scenarios. The alternative is both compiling, which you already accomplished. You did erase the type after all.

Comment: To use `assert` btw, you could be using the `typeid` operator, but since you're only using this functionality with the `assert` macro, you should be surrounding this kind of functionality with `#ifndef NDEBUG #endif` for performance/footprint reasons...

Comment: @ALX23z The purpose is to be able to store any type, at least when initializing something, but then not be able to re-assign the type of an object later. (While still maintaining the ability to put several things of different types in a container.) I don't know whether this is actually possible, however.

Comment: You can only produce runtime errors. As in general, at compile time, there is no way to know what type is stored inside.

Comment: There are a number of issues with the shown code, e.g. `Concept` is used before it's declared, the constructor of `TypeErased` is private, etc. Please make a [mre] so that others can just copy paste your code and see the errors you're getting. It makes the question much better (and increases the chances of someone helping out).

Comment: @cigien This is not a "fix my compiler error problem" - it is an academic question about whether implementing a particular design pattern with certain requirements is *possible*. Not every question requires a MWE - for some questions it doesn't make sense - this is one of those. Put another way, I could paste ~ 500 lines of source *which would actually compile* but this would *obfuscate the question being asked* and most people *would not bother to read it*.